# Why is the test with no arguments failing in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export function twoFer( arg : string ): string 
{
  if( arg !== "")
  {
    return "One for " + arg + ", one for me.";
  }
    return "One for you, one for me." ;
}
```

I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong. This is failing in the case when no argument is supplied.

```
describe('TwoFer', () => {
  it('no name given', () => {
    const expected = 'One for you, one for me.'
    expect(twoFer()).toEqual(expected)
  })
})
```

Output:

```
TEST FAILURE
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: "One for you, one for me."
Received: "One for undefined, one for me."
```

https://exercism.org/tracks/typescript/exercises/two-fer

Comment: Can you show the _test_? But note `undefined !== ""`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, I come from C++. I didn't know better

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know the way to show the test. I request you to write an answer to show what I am doing wrong.

Comment: They're on the Tests tab if you're using the online editor, `two-fer.test.ts` if you used the CLI to get the code locally.

Comment: You could set the default for the argument as `"you"`: `function twoFer (arg: string = 'you'): string` - then the whole `if` can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string parameter not specified doesn't contain an empty string; it contains `undefined`. You would want something like this:

```
export function twoFer(arg?: string): string
{
    if(typeof arg !== "undefined") {
        return "One for " + arg + ", one for me.";
    }
    return "One for you, one for me.";
}
```

UPDATE:

Alternatively, you can make `arg` a parameter with a default value instead to reduce redundancy.

```
export function twoFer(arg = "you"): string
{
    return "One for " + arg + ", one for me.";
}
```

Comment: `if(arg !== undefined)` would be clearer.

Comment: @CherryDT Attempting to compare an undefined variable throws a ReferenceError. You have to check the type.

Comment: That's not true. Attempting to compare an _undeclared_ variable (identifier, to be exact) would do that - but that's rarely ever a meaningful thing to do anyway. `arg` is declared, it's an argument of the function. The error message would say `x is not defined` but to avoid confusion I use the word "declared" here since "not defined" is **not** the same as being defined (i.e. declared) and holding the value `undefined`, as is the case here.